# Running the application on the iphone crashes

Tags: iphone, titanium

help solve the problem!

I have:
 --Mac OS X 10.7.2
 --Titanium Studio, build: 1.0.7.201112281340
 --Xcode, ver 4.2.1, Build 4D502
 --iPhone 5.0.1 iOs
 --application I am trying to write

When I try to run the application on the iPhone Device I get the error.

Hier is Console Log

```
[TRACE] app property, ti.android.runtime : rhino
[DEBUG] Detecting modules in /Users/<USER>/Documents/Titanium Studio Workspace/sinoptic/modules
[DEBUG] Detecting modules in /Users/<USER>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules
[INFO] Performing clean build
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<USER>/Library/Application     Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.0.1/iphone/builder.py", line 1418, in main
execute_xcode("iphoneos%s" % iphone_version,args,False)
  File "/Users/<USER>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.0.1/iphone/builder.py", line 1180, in execute_xcode
output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
  File "/Users/<USER>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.0.1/iphone/run.py", line 39, in run
sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 65
```

In /Users//Documents/Titanium Studio Workspace/sinoptic/build/iphone/build/build.log i have:

```
CodeSign build/Debug-iphoneos/ZeusLight.app
cd "/Users/<USER>/Documents/Titanium Studio Workspace/sinoptic/build/iphone"
setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "iPhone Developer: <CERTIFICATE HIER>" "--resource-rules=/Users/<USER>/Documents/Titanium Studio Workspace/sinoptic/build/iphone/build/Debug-iphoneos/ZeusLight.app/ResourceRules.plist" --entitlements "/Users/<USER>/Documents/Titanium Studio Workspace/sinoptic/build/iphone/build/ZeusLight.build/Debug-iphoneos/ZeusLight-universal.build/ZeusLight.xcent" "/Users/<USER>/Documents/Titanium Studio Workspace/sinoptic/build/iphone/build/Debug-iphoneos/ZeusLight.app"
/Users/<USER>/Documents/Titanium Studio Workspace/sinoptic/build/iphone/build/Debug-iphoneos/ZeusLight.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
CodeSign build/Debug-iphoneos/ZeusLight.app
(1 failure)
EXIT CODE WAS: 65

Exception detected in script:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<USER>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.0.1/iphone/builder.py", line 1418, in main
execute_xcode("iphoneos%s" % iphone_version,args,False)
  File "/Users/<USER>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.0.1/iphone/builder.py", line 1180, in execute_xcode
output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
  File "/Users/<USER>/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.0.1/iphone/run.py", line 39, in run
sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 65
```

Running on the emulator - there is no error, all is well.
The reason? This is driving me crazy!

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the "build" folder inside your app source directory. Then again build for device.